# " 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable" error occurs when I get dictionary keys into a list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My dictionay items are as follows,

```
dict_items([(3.0, 0), (2.0, 23), (1.0, 30), (4.0, 41)])
```

I need to access these dictionary values in terms of the key's index.In order to do that, I used `index=list(positions.keys()).pop(0)`

It renders an error as follows.

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Any pointers on how to solve this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you're overwriting the name "list" somewhere in your script? Like `list = ...`? Then when you try to use that as a cast to a list, it fails because your assignment is shadowing it...

Comment: @ Filipe Brandenburger, yes you are right. I have used 'list' in another place. I changed that name and solved the problem.